# Asymptotic approximation to exponential integral

Tags: integration, asymptotics

I have been asked to find the asymptotic approximation to the integral

$$E_n(x) = \int_1^\infty t^{-n}e^{-xt}\,{\rm d}t$$

where $n={\rm ord}(1)$ and $x\to\infty$ and then estimate the remainder.

I don't really have any clue how to do this however I have attempted something. Write

$$e^{-xt} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-xt)^k}{k!}$$

then

$$E_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^k}{k!}\int_1^\infty t^{k-n}\,{\rm d}t$$

However I'm not sure how to evaluate that integral. Could someone help?

Comment: $$E_1(x)\approx \frac{1}{x e^x}$$ as $x\to +\infty$. Can you prove this?

Answer (score 3):

As $k>n-1$ the integral in the decomposition you proposes diverges. You can write the original integral as $$\exp(-x)\int_0^\infty  (1+u)^{-n}\exp(-ux)du$$ and integrate by parts several times. Firstly $$E_n(x)=e^{-x}\left[\frac{1}{x}-\frac{n}{x}\int_0^\infty (1+u)^{-n-1}e^{-ux}du\right]$$ which gives the first order term. Going on gives you the following terms. Up to the first order $$E_n(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{x}+O(x^{-2}e^{-x})$$

Comment: Hi Paul, what made you think of using this substitution? Ps. you have somehow changed your integration from $du$ to $dx$.

Comment: @user2850514  Integration by parts is a classical procedure to calculate asymptotic expansions of that kind of integrals (see [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/2.3.i) for example. I edit the text to change $dx$ into $du$.

Answer (score 0):

$$E_1(x) = e^{-x}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-xt}}{t+1}\,dt = \frac{1}{x e^x}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{1+\frac{u}{x}}\,du $$
hence for large $x$, $E_1(x)$ is expected to behave like $\frac{1}{xe^x}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-u}\,du = \frac{1}{xe^x}.$ Additionally,
$$ \frac{1}{xe^x}-E_1(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 e^x}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ue^{-u}}{1+\frac{u}{x}}\,du $$
and by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ue^{-u}}{1+\frac{u}{x}}\,du \leq \frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}.$$