# Complexity of prime-finding (32/64 bit fixed-length ints!) algorithm

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, asymptotics

What's the time complexity for finding *all* primes up to N using the following algorithm:

```
primes = [2]
for pc in range(3, N, 2):
  for p in primes:
    if p * p > pc:
      primes.add(pc)
      break
    if pc mod p == 0:
      break
```

What I found is basically an [estimate](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/310490/51409) which can be expressed as an [integral](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+sqrt(x)+%2F+log(x)+dx) $\int{\frac{\sqrt{x}dx}{\log{x}}} = Ei(\frac{3}{2}\log x)$ which in turn according to comments and answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965851/asymptotic-approximation-to-exponential-integral) could be approximated using $E_1(x) \approx \frac{1}{x e^x}$. Since $E_1(x) = -Ei(-x)$,

$$Ei(1.5 \log x) = -E_1(-1.5 \log x) = \frac{-e^{1.5 \log x}}{-1.5 \log x} \approx \frac{e^{1.5 \log x}}{\log x} = \frac{x^{1.5}}{\log x}$$

- Are those calculations correct?
- The estimate is rough, any ideas how to improve it?
- Are there any better algorithms for fixed precision numbers (O(1) arithmetic operations) which are also simple to implement?

Comment: I'm confused with the `in range (3,2,N)`

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee odd numbers in [3, N], added comment in code

Comment: I remembered that for a particular task I don't need to find _all_ prime numbers, but only divisors of N. So there's obviously an $O(\sqrt{N})$ algorithm.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Sundaram